# Python can't find element that's there

Tags: python, for-loop, text

First and foremost, Python is not my first language, but a class I'm taking it is requiring it, so here I am... I'm using python with flask to make a website with a simple login/registration page. Making the pages is simple enough (I think?) however while setting the criteria for registration, the for loop I used to check if a user already exists worked at first, but with no changes to the code, it no longer does. I enter 'admin' as the username, but the loop can't find it despite existing in the txt file. Am I going insane or did I miss something?

```
def info():
    with open('passfile.txt', "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            text = line.split()
            username = text[0]
            print(text[0])
            password = text[1]

            yield username, password

def add_info(username, password):
    with open('passfile.txt', "a") as f:
        f.write(username + " " + password +"\n")


@week6.route("/registration", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """
    function to register a new user
    """
    username, password = info()

    if request.method == "POST":
        un = request.form.get("username")
        pw = request.form.get("password")
        secure = sc.hash(str(pw))
        register.secure = secure
        print(un)
        if un in username:
            flash("That username is already taken")
            return render_template("registration.html")
        
        if pw_verify(pw) == True:
            add_info(un, secure)
            flash("Your officially registered!")
                
    return render_template("registration.html")
```

Comment: Is the indention not right or am I not right?

Comment: the indentation is right. for some reason the stackoverflow code formatter messed it up

Comment: username is an iterator that returns the pair `(username, password)`.  You can't then test `if un in username` since a string doesn't match a pair.

Comment: To format your code, paste it in, highlight it, then click the {} button.

Comment: If the indentation here does not replicate your actual indentation, [edit] your question and fix it.

Comment: how would I then fix the issue? if I change username = info() to username, password = info() I get a ValueError

Comment: indentation should be fixed now

Comment: Why do you `yield username, password` and `username, password = info()`? That doesn't do what you think it does. Then, you check `un in username` but `username` is not a list of usernames in the file. Also, you do `lines = file.readlines()` but that leaves the line-ending intact, so your passwords are going to have an extra `\n` tacked on to the end which you are likely forgetting to strip out later. Note: You don't need to `lines = file.readlines()` and then `for line in lines:`. Simply `for line in file` is better because it won't load the entire file into memory at once.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) You will find it helpful to step through your code either in your head or (better) in a debugger.

Comment: In your own words, what does `yield username, password` do?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in how you're using your generator function:

```
def info():
    ...
    for line in lines:
        ...
        yield username, password
```

And then later:

```
username, password = info()
```

What the first function does (a generator function since it uses yield instead of return) is return an iterator that when you iterate over it gives you `(username, password)` tuples.

When you call it like `username, password = info()`, you're iterating it twice and assigning those tuples to `username` and `password`.

So, `username` might be `("user1", "secret_password")` and `password` might be `("admin", "admin_password")`, which clearly isn't what you intended.

It looks like what you wanted `info` to do, is return a list of usernames and a list of passwords. Changing it like this would work with your code:

```
def info():
    usernames = []
    passwords = []
    with open('passfile.txt', "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            username, password = line.split(maxsplit=1)

            usernames.append(username)
            passwords.append(password)

    return usernames, passwords
```

Although a quick fix, I would argue that that probably isn't the best way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using `yield` turns a function into a generator. That means `info` actually returns an iterator. The first step is to change your `info` call to this:

```
users = info()
```

Iterators calculate their values on the fly, so the `in` operator won't work with them. You'll need to consume the iterator to see its contents. You can modify your `if` statement to use the `any` function and a comprehension.

```
if any(u[0] == un for u in users):
```

The comprehension yields a boolean based on the first element of the tuple yielded from `info`. The `any` function returns True if any element is true.